# Is it possible for 2 threads lock a mutex at the same time (use mutex wrapper)?

Tags: c++

The question comes from an exmaple of [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

As far as I know, when I construct a new `thread`, it starts to execute immediately.

So I wonder, would `cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});` in `worker_thread()`, and `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);` in `main`, lock the mutex at the same time? Could this happen?

(From cppreference I know that `std::condition_variable::wait` and `std::lock_guard` would lock the mutex during the construction.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::string data;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;

void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});

    // after the wait, we own the lock.
    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";

    // Send data back to main()
    processed = true;
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";

    // Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
    // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);

    data = "Example data";
    // send data to the worker thread
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready = true;
        std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    cv.notify_one();

    // wait for the worker
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
    }
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';

    worker.join();
}
```

Comment: `std::condition_variable::wait   1) __Atomically releases lock__, blocks the current executing thread, and adds it to the list of threads waiting on *this. The thread will be unblocked when notify_all() or notify_one() is executed. It may also be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the reason, lock is reacquired and wait exits. If this function exits via exception, lock is also reacquired.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutex are meant to get a lock on resource, only 1 thread can get that lock. Locking of mutex is atomic, 2 threads cannot acquire a lock on mutex, if they can, then it defeats the purpose of mutex locks!

> Mutexes are built such that locking is an atomic operation: it will only complete on one thread at a time, regardless of how many threads are attempting to lock

Answer (score 1):

"Mutex" is a contraction of "mutual exclusion"; it's purpose is to allow only one thread to lock the mutex at any time.

That said, there's a serious problem in that example. It has a potential deadlock, because it tries too hard to sequence inherently non-sequential operations.

The problem occurs if `main` goes through its locking code, sets `ready` to `true`, and calls `notify()` before the new thread locks the mutex and calls `wait()`. If that happens, `main` will proceed to its call to `wait()` while the new thread is sitting in `wait()`, and neither one will notify the other one; they're both waiting for the other one to do something.

If you're unlucky, you won't see this when you're testing the code; it might happen that the new thread starts to `wait()` before the main thread calls `notify()`, and then the code will work as expected. That's unlucky because sooner or later it will lock up, most likely when you're demonstrating your code to your most important customer.

Comment: Wow, thankyou, you are right, I haven't noticed that. Maybe you should remind cppreference about this example.